# Is NSUserDefaults for Today Extensions broken in iOS 8 beta 5?

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios8, ios-app-extension

My Today Extensions works perfectly on beta 4, and I have implement a simple cache when Today Extensions first loaded.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.ReadWidget") // app group 
var feed = [String: String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    getCache()

    // The feed is empty
}

func parseRSS() {
    ...
    // Parse in background

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
          self.parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string:url))
          self.parser.delegate = self
          self.parser.parse() // populate the feed
          self.saveCache()    // Save the feed
          ...
        })
    })
}

func saveCache() {
    defaults.setObject(feed, forKey:"feed")
    defaults.synchronize()
}

func getCache() {
    if defaults.objectForKey("feed") {
        feed = defaults.dictionaryForKey("feed") as [String : String]
    }
    else {
        feed = [:]
    }
}
```

In beta 5, after `saveCache()`, and when `getCache()` back in Today Extension reloaded, I always got back an empty dictionary.

I am using `NSUserDefaults(suiteName:...)` to store cache. I have also tried `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` and the result is the same.

btw, which `NSUserDefaults` is the preferred method for loading and saving cache? The cache is not shared with the main app.

Comment: Consider the name: `NSUserDefaults`. It is not `NSUserDatabase` or `NSUserCache`. It is best not to use defaults for such data storage.

Comment: Please a full minimal example that can be copied into a project and tested.

Comment: It is not best use NSUserDefaults for a simple Dictionary with a few strings? I thought this is what recommended by Apple, especially for Today Extension.

Comment: I have the same problem with `NSUserDefaults` after updating to Beta 5 so it's probably a bug.

Comment: Do you use Dictionary as data type too? What problem do you face?

Comment: See others complained about this issue in Apple developer forum, so this is probably a bug. https://devforums.apple.com/message/1018520#1018520

Comment: Seems that this is fixed in GM.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var feed = [String:String]()

func getCache() {
    if defaults.objectForKey("feed") {
        feed = defaults.dictionaryForKey("feed") as [String : String]
    }
    else {
        feed = [:]
    }
    println("feed: \(feed)")
}
```

Comment: The feed is a global variable. Both getCache and saveCache uses it. Is something being clear away?

Comment: Is there any difference?

Comment: Not really but you have not provided a self-contained **minimal** test so there is no way to know.

Comment: From a testability (and design) POV it is best to pass values into and return them than using globals such as `feed`. In the current question code is is not shown where `feed` is set prior to `saveCache()`.

Comment: feed is set in self.parser.parse() as this is a RSS parser. It is OK as it is very difficult to condense all these into a minimal test, but thanks for your help. The code works prior to beta 5.